# Unicode subscript characters do not display

Tags: macos, font, unicode

None of my apps including Chrome, TextEdit, and MacVim can display the unicode character subscript t shown here -> ₜ

Example text:

```
graph Gₓ at time Uₜ
```

The subscript x displays fine but not the subscript t.

How do I fix this?

---

MacBookPro11,2
OS 10.11.6

Comment: How did you type it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked in Character Viewer that you actually have a font installed which contains this character?  It displays for me here.  My Character Viewer says the 3rd party font Symbola is the only one I have with it.  Why more fonts don't have it I don't know.  (U+209C)